# Is the term ‘Niven polynomial’ defined online, in English, only in Julian Havil’s book on the irrational numbers?

Tags: reference-request

The only place I can find the term ‘Niven polynomial’ explicitly defined online, in English, as such is in the online preview of Julian Havil’s book ‘The Irrationals: A Story of the Numbers You Can’t Count On’, on p. 116. Can someone point out one that I missed? It seems like it ought to be in at least one dictionary somewhere online.

Comment: They basically just come up in Niven's proof of pi's irrationality / a couple of similarly-themed proofs.

Comment: Page 123 http://bdmath.com/books/Julian%20Havil-The%20irrationals_%20a%20story%20of%20the%20numbers%20you%20can't%20count%20on-Princeton%20University%20Press%20(2012).pdf

Page 50 http://faculty.gvsu.edu/alayontf/talks/irrational_numbers.pdf

http://www.math.cmu.edu/~bobpego/21132/pinot.pdf